# Design database schema to support multi-tenant in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a School manager software in ASP that connects to an MYSQL DB. The software is working great when I deploy it in local machine for each user (SCHOOL), but I want to migrate software to AZURE cloud. The users will have an account to connect to the same app but data must not mix with other schools data. My problem is to find the best way to deploy and manage the database.

1. Must I  Deploy 1 DB for each school
2. All school DATA in the same DB.

I'm not sure my solutions are the best ways.

I don't want  ex STUDENT TABLE( content student for school X, for SCHOOL Y, ...)

please help to find the best solution.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Azure, really. You can create per-school DBs on Azure just like you do locally, or you can properly code a multi-tenant application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple possible ways to design schema to support multi-tenant. The simplicity of the design depends on the use case.

> Separate the data of every tenant (school) physically, i.e., one
>   schema must contain data related to only a specific tenant.

**Pros:**

1. Easy for A/B Testing. You can release updates which require database changes to some tenants and over time make it available for others.
2. Easy to move the database from one data-center to another. Support different SLA for backup for different customers.
3. Per tenant database level customization is easy. Adding a new table for customers, or modifying/adding a field becomes easy.
4. Third party integrations are relatively easy, e.g., connecting your data with Google Data Studio.
5. Scaling is relatively easy.
6. Retrieving data from one tenant is easy without worrying about the mixing up foreign key values.

**Cons:**

1. When you have to modify any field/table, then your application code needs to handle cases where the alterations are not completed in some databases.
2. Retrieving analytics across customers becomes difficult. Designing Queries for usage analysis becomes harder.
3. When integrating with other databases system, especially NoSQL, you will need more resources. e.g., indexing data in Elasticsearch for every tenant will require index per tenant, and if there are thousands of customers, it will result in creating thousands of shards.
4. Common data across tenants needs to be copied in every database

> Separate data for every tenant (school) logically, i.e., one schema
>   contains data for all the tenants.

**Pros:**

1. Software releases are simple.
2. Easy to query usage analytics across multiple tenants.

**Cons:**

1. Scaling is relatively tricky. May need database sharding.
2. Maintaining the logical isolation of data for every tenant in all the tables requires more attention and may cause data corruption if not handled at the application level carefully.
3. Designing database systems for the application that support multiple regions is complicated.
4. Retrieving data from a single tenant is difficult. (Remember: all the records will be associated with some other records using foreign keys.)

This is not a comprehensive list. These are based on my experiences with working on both the type of designs. Both the designs are common and are used by multiple organization based on the usecase.